# Would "Wherefore does the universe exist?" be an acceptable question for stack philosophy?

Tags: discussion

The question

> Wherefore does the universe exist?

Is about [metaphysics - the nature of being and reality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) And I would evaluate it on the following [constructive questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) criteria as:

0. inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”: Partially yes, as pointed out into the comments, the "wherefore" is combined with "cause" to form a the modern "why".
1. tend to have long, not short, answers: Since the answer to the question appears quite difficult to humans I expect it to have a relatively long answer when in markdown format.
2. *have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone*: I doubt if it is considered constructive, in this era it seems at most feasible to identify reasons which are not the reason the universe exists.
3. *invite sharing experiences over opinions*: The question does not invite sharing experiences nor opinions. Instead, it invites an argumentation, explanation or explanation on why an answer to that question might not be captured accurately in markdown.
4. insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references: Yes.
5. are more than just mindless social fun: Since it seems unlikely to be answered within the lives of many, some might discard the question as mindless social fun.

Yet I suspect it might be closed on being "too broad". Additionally I would expect it to be a duplicate but I could not find the question on philosophy stack exchange. Would the question be an acceptable question for the philosophy stack exchange?

Comment: "*Why*" should be qualified.  Today's English combines two older word into that one.  "Why" used to refer to cause, and "Wherefore" used to refer to purpose.  Which are you asking here?

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with those different concepts  but did not have the words for that! I think the essence would be in the "Wherefore" with the "cause" containing the how. Hence, when posing such a question requires a choice between those two, I would choose for "Wherefore".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, without further limitations, it would fall under "too broad."

Comment: Or "too narrow". If the Universe didn't exist, this question (or any other question) couldn't be asked, so the Universe *must* exist by definition.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think whether something must exist or not does not remove nor answer the question of why it exists, neither in the sense of "cause" nor "Wherefore".

Comment: @Mary, thank you for your insight, I have limited the question in response to the comment explaining the difference between "cause" and "wherefore", does this change your answer?